# How to import django model into a script?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm writing a script to import data into an existing Django model:

```
import csv
from django.db import models
from movies.models import Movie
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
        # _, created = Movie.title.get_or_create(
        #     title=row[0],
        #     )
```

But I'm running into this error when trying to import my model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "import.py", line 3, in <module> 
        from movies.models import Movie
ImportError: No module named 'movies'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, load your django settings in a similar manner as in your manage.py file. In this scenario, "lists" is the project name, and "movies" is the app name.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "lists.settings")

import csv
from django.db import models
from movies.models import Movie
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
        # _, created = Movie.title.get_or_create(
        #     title=row[0],
        #     )
```

Lastly, make sure to place the script in the project's root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your app 'lists' in settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS ?
Also try migrating your models using
`python manage.py migrate`
The approach seems to be right and its the standard way you use csv module.

You can edit your question with traceback for detailed understanding of your issue.

Comment: My app is actually called 'movies' (which is registered), and the project is 'lists.' And there's nothing to migrate. The app and model work perfectly when I start up the server, but when I try to run a script, the issue appears.

Comment: Since your application name is movies, you should import your models in this way:
from movies.models import Movie

Comment: Mmm. I tried that but the error is now "ImportError: No module named 'movies'"

Comment: and I am assuming you registered you app 'movies' in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yep, 'movies' is registered.

Comment: Have you created your app via django-admin.py startapp <app_name>?
If no then include __init__.py in your movies folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82500/discussion-between-ajay-gupta-and-nitinsavant).